# How does a Android TextView breaks the text into lines?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need a way to break a text into lines like a TextView. I saw that the TextView uses [Dynamic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html)- / [Static](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html)- / [BoringLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html)s to do that.

With this information I wrote my own method but the text breaks are not the same. If the fontsize is really small the lines are to long :-(

```
public static String ellipsize(final String text, final TextAppearanceSpan textAppearance, final int avail, final int maxLines) {

   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
      return null;
   }

   final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   final TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
   paint.setTextSize(textAppearance.getTextSize());
   paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textAppearance.getFamily(), textAppearance.getTextStyle()));

   final float ellipsisWidth = paint.measureText("\u2026");

   final StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, avail, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, true);
   final int lineCount = layout.getLineCount();

   final int lines = lineCount < maxLines ? lineCount : maxLines;

   for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

      final int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(i);
      final int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i);
      String substring = text.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);

      if ((i == (maxLines - 1)) && (lineCount > maxLines)) {

         final int nextLineStart = layout.getLineStart(i + 1);
         final int nextLineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i + 1);

         final String nextSubstring = text.substring(nextLineStart, nextLineEnd);
         final String lastLine = substring.concat(nextSubstring);

         substring = TextUtils.ellipsize(lastLine, paint, avail - ellipsisWidth, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END, true, null).toString();
      }

      builder.append(substring);
   }

   return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think you should look at the EditText of Android source code rather than starting with TextView. So, you might have to extend EditText to suit your needs, i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that it is impossible to create my own TextPaint object which looks like the one from the TextView.

So now I copy the TextPaint object from the TextView and change the text size and font face.

I think it is working now.

```
/**
 * Returns the original text if it fits in the specified width (<code>avail</code>) with 
 * the properties of the specified TextAppearanceSpan (<code>textAppearance</code>), or,
 * if it does not fit, a truncated copy with ellipsis character added at the end 
 * (<code>TextUtils.TruncateAt.END</code>).
 * 
 * @param paint
 *           the TextPaint from the TextView
 * @param text
 *           the text to truncated
 * @param textAppearance
 *           text typeface, size, and style
 * @param avail
 *           the available width
 * @param maxLines
 *           maximum number of displayed lines
 * @return the original text or a truncated copy
 * @see TextView#getPaint()
 * @see TextAppearanceSpan
 * @see TextUtils.TruncateAt#END
 */
public static String ellipsize(final TextPaint paint,
                               final String text,
                               final TextAppearanceSpan textAppearance,
                               final int avail,
                               final int maxLines) {

   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
      return null;
   }

   final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   paint.setTextSize(textAppearance.getTextSize());
   paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textAppearance.getFamily(), textAppearance.getTextStyle()));

   final StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, avail, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
   final int lineCount = layout.getLineCount();

   final int lines = lineCount < maxLines ? lineCount : maxLines;

   for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

      final int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(i);
      final int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i);
      String substring = text.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);

      if ((i == (maxLines - 1)) && (lineCount > maxLines)) {

         final String lastLine = substring.concat("\u2026");
         substring = TextUtils.ellipsize(lastLine, paint, avail, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END, true, null).toString();
      }

      builder.append(substring);
   }

   return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: `text = MyTextUtils.ellipsize(<TextView>.getPaint(),
                             text,
                             <TextAppearanceSpan>,
                             <TextView>.getWidth(),
                             <max lines>);`

Comment: Where are you taking care of "Spanned" in all this code?